# PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, logistic-regression

I see this question has been asked before but I can't find a situation that applies to my specific circumstance.

I have the following code:

```
list_of_responses =['Respiratory','GI_System','Systemic_Other','EXP_TEST_COVMEN_PUI_MISC','MED_ALERT_CPR_SHOCK_SEPSIS','Lymph_Node_Neck','Ear','Mouth_Sores','Eye','Cough','Nasal_Congestion','SOB_WOB_Hyp_Desat','PNA','Abdominal_Pain','Nausea','Vomiting','Diarrhea','Rash','Fever','Weak_Fatigue','Bodyaches','Dizziness','Fussy','Poor_PO_Dehydration','Tachycardia','COVID_Exposure','COVID_Test','COVID_PUI','CP','ST','HA','Wheezing_Asthma','Loss_Taste_Smell']


for cc in list_of_responses:
        reg_model = smf.logit("Covid_pos ~  cc + C(RACE_GROUP_N, Treatment(0)) + C(Age_Group_N, Treatment(0)) + C(Insurance_Type_Group, Treatment(0))",
            data = df_merged2).fit()
        reg_model_odds = pd.DataFrame(np.exp(reg_model.params), columns= ['OR'])
        reg_model_odds['z-value']= reg_model.pvalues
        reg_model_odds[['2.5%', '97.5%']] = np.exp(reg_model.conf_int())
        reg_model_odds['OR'] = round(reg_model_odds['OR'], 2)
        reg_model_odds['2.5%'] = round(reg_model_odds['2.5%'], 2)
        reg_model_odds['97.5%'] = round(reg_model_odds['97.5%'], 2)
        reg_model_odds["OR 95% CI"]= reg_model_odds['OR'].map(str)+' ('+reg_model_odds['2.5%'].map(str)+', '+reg_model_odds['97.5%'].map(str)+')'
        reg_model_oddsOR=reg_model_odds["OR 95% CI"]
        reg_model_oddsOR
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and cc (5253 versus 1)
    Covid_pos ~  cc + C(RACE_GROUP_N, Treatment(0)) + C(Age_Group_N, Treatment(0)) + C(Insurance_Type_Group, Treatment(0))
                 ^^
```

I see in previous posts that it may be due to how the columns are formatted and the formula, but I think my columns appears to be properly formatted and the formula is correct. Not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

[PatsyError: Number of rows mismatch between data argument and column (statsmodels)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740329/patsyerror-number-of-rows-mismatch-between-data-argument-and-column-statsmodel)

This is what my data look like:

```
ID   RACE_GROUP_N Age_Group_N... Covid_pos  Asymptomatic  Fever  Cough ...
0     1               0            1             0        1      0
1     0               2            0             0        0      1
2     3               3            1             1        0      0
3     2               1            1             0        1      0
4     3               2            0             1        0      0
5     0               4            1             0        1      0
```